# Is there a way to apply a function over all rows with the same values in a NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numerical-integration

Let's say we have a matrix, A, that has the following values:

```py
In [2]: A
Out[2]: 
array([[1, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 5],
       [1, 1, 7],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 9],
       [2, 1, 5],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 8],
       [2, 2, 3]])
```

is there a way to apply a function, e.g., `np.mean`, row-wise for values of the third column where first and the second column are equal, i.e, to get matrix B:

```py
In [4]: B
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 1, 5],
       [1, 2, 6],
       [2, 1, 5],
       [2, 2, 4]])
```

My actual use case is much more complex. I have a large matrix with ~1M rows and 4 columns. The first three columns correspond to (x, y, z) coordinate of a point in a point-cloud and the forth column is a value of some function f where f = f(x, y, z). I have to perform integration along x-axis (the first column in a matrix) for all (y, z) pairs that are equal. I have to end up with a matrix with some number of rows which corresponds to the number of unique (y, z) pairs and three columns: y-axis, z-axis, and the value that is obtained from integration. I have a few ideas but all those ideas include multiple for-loops and potential memory issues.

Is there any way to perform this in a vectorized fashion?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 5],
       [1, 1, 7],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 9],
       [2, 1, 5],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 8],
       [2, 2, 3]]) 

uniquePairs = np.unique(A[:,:2], axis=0)
output = np.empty((uniquePairs.shape[0], A.shape[1]))
for iPair, pair in enumerate(uniquePairs):
    output[iPair,:2] = pair
    output[iPair,2] = np.mean( A[np.logical_and(A[:,0]==pair[0], A[:,1]==pair[1]),2] )
    
print(output)
```

The output is

```
[[1. 1. 5.]
 [1. 2. 6.]
 [2. 1. 5.]
 [2. 2. 4.]]
```

There is also a more compact variation, but perhaps with less readability:

```
uniquePairs = np.unique(A[:,:2], axis=0)
output = np.array([[*pair,  np.mean(A[np.logical_and(A[:,0]==pair[0], A[:,1]==pair[1]),2])] for iPair, pair in enumerate(uniquePairs)])
```

Comment: Usually we use `np.zeros` or `np.empty` to create an initial array.  `np.ndarray` is low level creator that is best reserved for special cases (such as making an array from an existing buffer).

Comment: Understood. I did not know that and thought ndarray was the way to create an uninitialized array. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `pandas`, if you have a lot of data :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(A, columns = ['id1','id2' ,'value'])
B = df.groupby(['id1','id2'])['value'].mean().reset_index().to_numpy()
```

output:

```
>>
[[1. 1. 5.]
 [1. 2. 6.]
 [2. 1. 5.]
 [2. 2. 4.]]
```

I assume this is being the fastest way

Comment: above all, it is the only right answer to what the OP is asking for.

Comment: It may be easy to do this with `pandas`, but I wouldn't go so far as to make speed claims - at least not without testing.  In my limited experience, setting up the `groupby` is relatively fast, but the aggregation can be slow.  `mean` aggregation may use builtin code and be faster than most.

Comment: @hpaulj I assume it would be faster than any looping methods.

Comment: But what if `pandas` does looping under the covers?  `pandas.apply` is notoriously slow; I don't know about the groupings.  `pandas` also keeps track of row indices, which slows it down compared to most `numpy` operations.

Comment: I added some timings to my answer

Comment: @hpaulj apply is slow because that specific method is meant to be applied row by row. also your timings seems like is based on small sample data , how about you rerun your timing test on an array with 1million rows? my tests on my machine shows , pandas takes 1.27 second , while looping (either defaultdict method or others) takes around ~ 11 sec

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array(
    [
        [1, 1, 3],
        [1, 1, 5],
        [1, 1, 7],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 9],
        [2, 1, 5],
        [2, 2, 1],
        [2, 2, 8],
        [2, 2, 3],
    ]
)

result = np.mean(A[:, 2], where=A[:, 0] == A[:, 1])
```

This might be what you're looking for. You can use `A[:, n]` to access a column.

Comment: Based on the posted output, I think the poster wants to compute the mean for all the rows that have the same (column0, column1) pair.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` does not have builtin `grouping` tools. And since the groups differ in length, they will require separate `mean` calls.  So some level of iteration will be required.

`defaultdict` is a handy way of grouping values

```
In [64]: from collections import defaultdict
In [65]: dd = defaultdict(list)
In [66]: for row in A:
    ...:     dd[tuple(row[:2])].append(row[-1])
In [67]: dd
Out[67]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {(1, 1): [3, 5, 7],
             (1, 2): [3, 9],
             (2, 1): [5],
             (2, 2): [1, 8, 3]})
In [68]: {k: np.mean(v) for k, v in dd.items()}
Out[68]: {(1, 1): 5.0, (1, 2): 6.0, (2, 1): 5.0, (2, 2): 4.0}
```

We can create an array of the means with:

```
In [72]: np.array([k + (np.mean(v),) for k, v in dd.items()])
Out[72]: 
array([[1., 1., 5.],
       [1., 2., 6.],
       [2., 1., 5.],
       [2., 2., 4.]])
```

Some comparative times - with the usual caveat about scaling to larger arrays.

```
In [99]: %%timeit
    ...: dd = defaultdict(list)
    ...: for row in A:
    ...:     dd[tuple(row[:2])].append(row[-1])
    ...: np.array([k + (np.mean(v),) for k, v in dd.items()])
132 µs ± 92.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [97]: %%timeit
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=["id1", "id2", "value"])
    ...: B = df.groupby(["id1", "id2"])["value"].mean().reset_index().to_numpy()
2.27 ms ± 123 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [102]: %%timeit
     ...: uniquePairs = np.unique(A[:, :2], axis=0)
     ...: output = np.ndarray((uniquePairs.shape[0], A.shape[1]))
     ...: for iPair, pair in enumerate(uniquePairs):
     ...:     output[iPair, :2] = pair
     ...:     output[iPair, 2] = np.mean(
     ...:         A[np.logical_and(A[:, 0] == pair[0], A[:, 1] == pair[1]), 2]
     ...:     )
279 µs ± 216 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Another idea that needs more work to be fully functional, but has promise when scaling up is:

```
In [106]: %%timeit
     ...: out = np.zeros((2, 2))
     ...: np.add.at(out, (A[:, 0] - 1, A[:, 1] - 1), A[:, -1])
     ...: cnt = np.zeros((2, 2))
     ...: np.add.at(cnt, (A[:, 0] - 1, A[:, 1] - 1), 1)
     ...: res = out / cnt
38.9 µs ± 62.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Comment: how big is the array , make an array with 1 million rows and timeit